# Hilbert polynomials of graded algebras evaluated at negative numbers

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, graded-rings-modules, hilbert-function

Let $k$ be a field and let $R$ be a commutative (standard) graded $k$-algebra, that is, $R=\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty R_n$ with $R_0=k$ (and $R=k[R_1]$). The Hilbert function $h_R:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is given by $h_R(n)=\dim_k R_n$. When $n\gg 0$, it is known that $h_R(n)$ agrees with a polnyomial $p_R(n)$ in $n$ with rational coefficients.

In many theorems in combinatorics, polynomials which count objects have combinatorially sensible meaning when evaluated at negative numbers. For example, the chromatic polynomial $\chi_G(x)$ of a graph, which counts the number of proper colorings of $G$ with $x$ colors, has the delightful property that $\chi_G(-1)$ is the number of acyclic orientations of $G$.

One other example, intimately related to the Hilbert function, is that of Ehrhart polynomials. The Ehrhart polynomial $E_P(n)$ of a convex integral polytope $P$ inside $\mathbb{R}^m$ is the number of lattice points of $\mathbb{Z}^m$ inside the $n$th dilate $nP$. It is also known that $E_P(-n)$ is the number of interior lattice points (up to sign) of $nP$. For some (all?) polytopes, the Ehrhart polynomial agrees with the Hilbert polynomial of an associated affine semigroup ring.

In general, or in the specific context of affine semigroup rings $R$, is there some sensible (algebraic or combinatorial) meaning to $p_R(-n)$, or even $p_R(-1)$?

Comment: This is a cross-post from Math StackExchange, where it has received no answers or comments. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4670444/hilbert-polynomials-of-graded-algebras-evaluated-at-negative-numbers

Comment: You can also do this with nonstandardly graded commutative $k$-algebras, and get interesting answers. The Hilbert function is then not polynomial, but "polynomial on residue classes" - in other words, there exists a modulus $m$, and a set of $m$ polynomials $p_i$ such that if $n$ is congruent to $i$ modulo $m$, you apply $p_i$ to get $h_R(n)$. As an example, if $G$ is a compact Lie group, and $R=H^*(BG,k)$ (in any characteristic) then $h_r(n)$ is zero for $n$ between $-\dim G$ and $-1$. This follows from a calculation of Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity, contained in a paper of Peter Symonds.

Comment: @DaveBenson Thank you for the reference! I believe this is called "quasi-polynomial" behavior, isn't that right? It is very interesting to know that there are some negative zeroes of $h_R(n)$. Is there any, say topological, interpretation about the Lie group that comes about from knowing the zeroes of the Hilbert polynomial of these rings?

Comment: It goes by various names, including quasi-polynomial. Graham Higman called it PORC, for "polynomial on residue classes". The functions I was referring to are only eventually quasi-polynomial, which Higman called "almost PORC". The zeroes in the case of a compact Lie group are related to a sort of derived Gorenstein property with a shift equal to $-\dim G$.

Comment: @DaveBenson Yes, I was thinking of it asymptotically, so "almost" is good enough for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This answer is essentially the same as that of Phil Tosteson, written
before I saw that post. I also mention a non-Cohen-Macaulay example at
the end.

If $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay (but not necessarily generated in degree
one), then $R$ has associated with it a *canonical module*
$\Omega(R)$ which can be graded so its Hilbert function agrees with
$(-1)^d p_R(-n)$ for $n$ sufficiently large, where $d$ is the Krull
dimension of $R$ or $\Omega(R)$. If $R$ has $n$ generators then it can
be regarded as a module over the polynomial ring
$A=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. One can then define $\Omega(R) =
\mathrm{Ext}^{n-d}_A(R,A)$. If $R$ is not Cohen-Macaulay, then there are
"correction terms" to the formula $p_R(-n) = (-1)^d\mathrm{HQ}(\Omega(R))$,
where $\mathrm{HQ}$ denotes Hilbert quasipolynomial. Namely,
$$ p_R(-n) = (-1)^d \sum_{i=0}^d
      (-1)^i\mathrm{HQ}\left( \mathrm{Ext}^{n-d+i}_A(R,A)\right). $$
(If $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay, then only the term indexed by $i=0$ doesn't
vanish.)  I don't know where this result is stated in precisely this
form, but it is equivalent to Theorem 6.4 of my book *Combinatorics
and Commutative Algebra*, second ed. Theorem 8.2 gives an example,
stated in terms of Hilbert series rather than Hilbert quasipolynomials.

Comment: Thank you! I had looked at your book and several others when thinking about Ehrhart polynomials recently. In fact, your paper about combinatorial reciprocity inspired my initial thoughts about this question!

Comment: Although it is quite obvious, $A = k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ in the above, yes? ($A$ is not defined).

Comment: @Pedro: yes $A=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$.

Answer (score 12):

For $n \gg 0$, we have that ${\rm dim~} R_n = {\rm dim~}  H^0(X, \mathcal O(n))$, where $X = {\rm Proj}(R) \subseteq \mathbb P(R_1^{\vee})$ is the projective scheme associated to $R$ and $\mathcal O(n)$ is the degree $n$ line bundle.

In fact, we have that for all **integer** values that $$p_R(n) = \chi(H^*(X,\mathcal O(n))) := \sum_{i} (-1)^i {\rm dim} ~ H^i(X, \mathcal O(n)).$$

This gives an interpretation of $p_R(n)$ for negative values,  but it is somewhat abstract in general.  However in special cases (e.g. when $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay) there are more concrete interpretations of these Euler characteristics.

Let $K$ be a dualizing complex for $X$.  Then ${\rm Ext}^*_X(\mathcal O,\mathcal O(-n))$ is graded dual to $Ext^*(\mathcal O(-n),K) = H^*(X, K(n))$.  Thus in particular, if $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay of dimension $d$, so that $K = \omega_X[d]$  for some dualizing sheaf $\omega_X$, then we get that for all $n \gg 0$, that $$p_R(-n) = (-1)^d \chi(H^*(X, \omega_X(n)) = (-1)^d {\rm dim~} H^0(X, \omega_X(n)).$$ (We used that $n \gg 0$ in the last equality).  So in this case, the negative values of $p_R(n)$ can be interpreted as the graded dimensions of the dualizing module of $R$.

As an example, you can take $R = k[x_0, \dots, x_d]$ so that $X = \mathbb P^d$ and $\omega_X = \mathcal O(-d-1)$ and one recovers the combinatorial reciprocity $${-n + d \choose d} =  (-1)^d {n -1 \choose d}.$$

Also this story is closely related to Ehrhart reciprocity, because Ehrhart functions are Hilbert functions on toric varieties.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you for the answer. I suppose I should have expected a canonical module would show up. I am most interested in non-Cohen-Macaulay examples, but this gives me somewhere to start.

Comment: (I liked both answers, but accepted Richard Stanley's because I was looking for references and he included a reference.)